# how can i pass json from php to js and manipulate it?

Tags: php, javascript, json, caching

here is what i want to do

1. i use codeigniter directory_map() function to map a folder save it as $map;

   ```
    $map = directory_map($this->rootdir.$this->session->userdata('user_name'));
   ```
2. then i encode the $map and echo it out

   ```
    echo $dir = json_encode($map);
   ```
3. what i want is save the $dir somehow.so when user open one of the folder i can use js to get the folder's content from the saved $dir json file, instead of communicate to server.if this make sense then how can i save the $dir json file or how to get it in the js file.

is there  a better way to do that?

Comment: I usually use David Walsh's (not sure about the name of the technique, I just call it by his name because that's the first result in Google) solution for Ajax cashing, check it out http://davidwalsh.name/cache-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use the method mentioned [here](http://davidwalsh.name/cache-ajax), which is basically along the following outline:

**Update:** *(I think I confused you a bit) The following is Javascript code*

```
//Global object to store the cache
cache = {};
function makeRequest(requested_data){
   request_hash = hash(requested_data);
   if (cache[request_hash]){
       handleData(cache[request_hash]);
   }
   else{
       //Make Ajax call, get data response back and store it in the cache
       request_hash = hash(requested_data);
       cache[request_hash] = data;
       handleData(data);
   }
}
```

**Note:** for `hash()`, you can use any hashing algorithm out there, you don't really need a cryptography-level hash, just something to create a basic signature. I use the [Javascript implementation of Java's `hashCode()`](http://werxltd.com/wp/2010/05/13/javascript-implementation-of-javas-string-hashcode-method/)

Comment: you mean i save the $dir in cache using php? but how the js can get the cache?